Is there a way to dynamically change if a Window is enabled/disabled in Compose Desktop?
I have a DecoratedWindow, leveraging jewel. But, the behavior is the same with Window.
class DecoratedWindowImpl : DecoratedWindowInterface {
    @Composable
    override fun Create(
        state: WindowState,
        enabled: Boolean,
        onCloseRequest: () -> Unit,
        content: @Composable DecoratedWindowScope.() -> Unit,
    ) {
        DecoratedWindow(
            state = state,
            enabled = enabled,
            onCloseRequest = onCloseRequest,
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}

If I trigger re-composition up stream but passing in a new enabled parameter (I can debug and see the new enabled param change in here), but the window remains enabled. I have also tried window.isEnabled = enabled and the result is the same. If I start the window as disabled then it works, that is the window is disabled. Is this expected behavior?

The problem lies in enabled: Boolean which does not track state changes.
You should be using a MutableState of the field as in enabled: MutableState<Boolean> function parameter.
When initializing it always remember to wrap it in a remember function as in
var isWindowEnabled = remember { mutableStateOf(true) } to avoid remaking it in recompositions.
Now changing the value is as easy as: isWindowEnabled.value = !isWindowEnabled.value
For the final product:
fun someFunction(
    isWindowEnabled: MutableState<Boolean>
) {
    Window(
        state = state,
        enabled = isWindowEnabled.value,
        onCloseRequest = onCloseRequest,
    ) {
        content()
    }
}

Note: You can also declare it with the by keyword as in var isWindowEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) } if you don't plan on using in the function you pass it to, because you cannot reassign a parameter.
At that case you can leave the parameter as isWindowEnabled: Boolean
